# asp file upload rendered as DispHTMLInputElement, Hence files attribute not available.. Any alternative?

Tags: asp.net

The code works fine in chrome, IE. The issue crops up when put to Enterprise mode in IE. Have to use this mode itself. Needed alternative to either 'files','files.length' attribute or to convert from DispHTMLInputElement to HTMLInputElement. Thanks in advance :)

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileAttachment" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" CssClass="uploadFileCntrl"/>                                                    
<button id="lnkUpload" class="btn lnkButton btn-primary uploadFile" onclick="javascript:saveDivToHidden();lnkUploadClick();return false;">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>Upload
</button>
```

JS:

```
        var fileInput = $('#<%= fileAttachment.ClientID %>').get(0);                   
        var files = fileInput.files;            
        var test;
        if (files.length == 0) {
            alert("No files");
        }
        else {                
            document.getElementById('loadinganimation').style.display = 'block';
            $('*').css('cursor', 'wait');
        }
```